# Re-sizable div - allow user to grab any edge of div to resize and simultaneously resize all divs

Tags: css

I have a React app with two vertical divs. I have added the following css to allow end-users to freely control the size of divs:

```
resize: horizontal;
overflow: auto;
```

Now the users can resize divs, but they are only able to do so by grabbing the lower right corner of the div:

[current divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51YPc.png)

What I would like to achieve, is for the users to be able to grab anywhere in between the divs and resize them, like that:

[desired divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FLQ5.png)

What I am also seeing that when I resize the left div, the right one just moves around instead of being resized - and what I would actually like to achieve, is for the second one to fill the rest of the screen when the first one is resized.

I am including a code snippet below. I tried researching this but don't even know what keywords to use to describe this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

```css
.myDiv1 {
 resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    }
    
.myDiv2 {
 resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
<div class="myDiv1">div 1</div>
<div class="myDiv2">div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like below?

I included a `container` class for the parent div and gave it a set width for the purpose of this example.

`myDiv1` and `myDiv2` were changed to **100% width** instead of 50%.

EDIT: I also included a `min-width` on `myDiv1` and `myDiv2` because when they were resized to a small width the height would change. The `min-width` prevented this.

```css
.myDiv1 {
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    }
    
.myDiv2 {
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    }
    
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="myDiv1">div 1</div>
<div class="myDiv2">div 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work too well - what I actually need is to both divs always fill the 100% width of the screen, so if the first one is downsized, the second one should fill the rest of the screen automatically, and the other way around. The proposed solution also requires for the user to grab by the corner, not anywhere between the divs like shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FLQ5.png